Including exogenous variable in BEKK equation
I am trying to solve for inclusion of 1 exogenous variable in my BEKK-GARCH equation. The literature speaks about it, however I am not able to find a relevant package in R that could allow me to include exogenous variable directly in BEKK-GARCH equation.
Can anyone pls help me on this?
